# How to add special permission to application?

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, google, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-play-services

I removed too much system apps last time and I reinstalled Google Play Services (GmsService) from .apk file from backup.

However, its component `com.google.android.gms.persistent` needs permission `OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS` and there is no way to add it using `adb grant` command because it's a special permission.

Without this permission it's constantly restarting and this causes high CPU usage and battery drain.

Logcat:

```
12-01 11:59:37.352 26458 26458 E DeviceDoctorHandler: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 11:59:37.352 26458 26458 E DeviceDoctorHandler: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 26458
12-01 11:59:37.352 26458 26458 E DeviceDoctorHandler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application co.g.App: java.lang.SecurityException: addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10009 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.
```

What I tried is to edit `/data/system/packages.xml` file and add permission manually:

```
<item name="android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS" granted="true" flags="0" />
```

However, `packages.xml` is restored after reboot and manual changes are lost.

How to add this permission or how to reinstall GmsService with all required permissions?

Comment: You need to install GMS as privileged system apps. Then add `android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS` to `/system/etc/permissions/privapp-permissions.xml`.

Comment: Isn't that the answer to the question, even if it's short?

Comment: @IrfanLatif, no such file on my device (Android 6.0.1)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the Android 6 tag. It was [added](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/964d2ebb94c41d2cf1fb45b534e86c10e0ced3ac) in Android 8. Related documentation: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist. Before that, IIRC, every privileged app was granted the requested permissions with the `signature|privileged` protection level.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I followed these tutorials from command line:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/trial-turn-any-app-to-system-app-and-automatically-install-after-factory-reset-totally-irremovable.4206825/

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/what-is-the-right-way-to-turn-an-app-into-a-system-app-under-android-oreo-and-above.4229763/

But if we had the app installed previously, then we must fix paths in `/data/system/packages.xml` and remove (or back-up under another name) `/data/system/packages.xml.mbak` to prevent overwriting changes in packages.xml.

Now I will observe...